# routing error when adding a new button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following is the error which I am getting, when I tried to add a button named decrement and implement it

```
No route matches {:controller=>"line_items", :product_id=>#<Product id: 2, title: "Harry Potter", description: "Its drama cum adventure cum suspense cum thriller, ...", image_url: "harry-potter_25.png", price: #<BigDecimal:b068140,'0.1E3',4(8)>, created_at: "2013-03-15 07:21:26", updated_at: "2013-03-18 11:57:13">, :action=>"decrement"}
```

Comment: How you implemented the button? It would be easy to dig it if you would paste that button implementation.

Comment: <%= button_to 'Remove from cart', decrement_line_items_path(:product_id => product), :method => :put, :remote => true %>

Comment: modify this like `:product_id => product.id`

Comment: earlier i used the same format i didnt get any errors, i think that is not the error!!

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you pasted your implementation code for button_to along with the error.

Also, you seem to be passing the entire product object in your button_to call against product_id

```
#<Product id: 2, title: "Harry                 Potter", description: "Its drama cum adventure cum suspense cum thriller, ...", image_url:        "harry-potter_25.png", price: #<BigDecimal:b068140,'0.1E3',4(8)>
```

Instead only try product.id

Answer (score 0):

replace `:product_id => product` with `:product_id => product.id` in the paath of the button

```
<%= button_to 'Remove from cart', decrement_line_items_path(:product_id => product.id), :method => :put, :remote => true %>
```

Comment: I have done the same thing, what u suggested, plz check my code once again.

Comment: Where is the code??? If it is the same what you pasted in the comment for the question, then check there is `:product_id => product`.